# How do I convert nested python lists to c structures?

Tags: python, c, list, structure

Ive been given a "json parser" python module that parses json files and returns a list of structures from the json file. Ive been asked to write a python module that takes this list and converts it into a ".h" file filled with c structures. My problem is that the json files can contain many nested lists (meaning nested lists within nested lists etc. etc.) and i just cant seem to get the right code to access these. 
Also every element of these lists has a key-value pair called "position" and i want to be able to sort the structures after this key-value pair and create a ".h" file with the sorted structures but im not sure if my code will do the trick.

My idea was to create a for loop that goes through the list and if it finds another list within that list checks this nested list for more nested lists etc. Im fairly new to python, could i solve this problem with a recursive function? If so, how?

method to go through the lists (only works for nested lists in the first list)

```
def test(liste):
        for inner_l in liste:
            for item in inner_l:
                print(item)
```

my sort function

```
def takeFourth(elem):
        return elem[3]

neueListe = neueListe + x.sort(key=takeFourth)
```

expected results, final .h file should look like this:

```
struct SubStructOfSubStruct
{
    int MyInteger;
};

struct ThirdSubStructType
{
    float MyFloatValue;
    double MyDoubleValue;
    struct SubStructOfSubStructType SubStructOfSubStruct;
};

struct SubStructType
{
    float MyFloatValue;
    double MyDoubleValue;
};

struct SecondSubStructType
{
    int MyInteger;
};

struct Toplevel
{
    struct ThirdSubStructType ThirdSubStruct;
    struct SubStructType SubStruct;
    char MyString[10];
    boolean MyBoolValue;
    double MyDoubleValue;
    float MyFloatValue;
    int MyInteger;
    struct SecondSubStructType SecondSubStruct;
};
```

This is where im at, this is the list that the parser returns that i want to go through and create structures of:
(the last value in the lists is the "position" value that i want to sort after)

```
[['SubStructOfSubStructType ', [['Integer', 'MyInteger', 33, 0]]], 
['ThirdSubStructType ', [['TreeNode', 'SubStructOfSubStructType', 'SubStructOfSubStruct', 2], ['Double', 'MyDoubleValue', 100, 0], ['Float', 'MyFloatValue', 22, 1]]], 
['SecondSubStructType', [['Integer', 'MyInteger', 333, 0]]], 
['SubStructType', [['Double', 'MyDoubleValue', 1000, 0], ['Float', 'MyFloatValue', 222, 1]]], 
['Toplevel', [['TreeNode', 'ThirdSubStructType', 'ThirdSubStruct', 7], ['Float', 'MyFloatValue', 2, 1], ['Boolean', 'MyBoolValue', False, 2], ['Double', 'MyDoubleValue', 10, 0], ['Integer', 'MyInteger', 3, 3], ['TreeNode', 'SecondSubStructType', 'SecondSubStruct', 6], ['String', 'MyString', 'Leer', 4], ['TreeNode', 'SubStructType','SubStruct',5]]]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For recursive list processing, you need to identify whether what you are looking at is a list or a leaf:

```
def test(liste):
    if isinstance(liste,list):
        for inner_l in liste:
            test(inner_l)
    else:
        print('item: {}'.format(liste))
```

Since you want to be able to locate structs and treat them as a unit, it might help to have helper functions to identify stuff you're looking for. You can use the same technique to look for a pattern of a label followed by a single list of members:

```
def is_struct(liste):
    return not isinstance(liste[0],list) and isinstance(liste[1],list) and len(liste) == 2
```

Then you can put them together:

```
def test(liste):
    if isinstance(liste,list):
        if is_struct(liste):
            print('struct {}'.format(liste[0]))
            for item in liste[1]:
                print('  var: {}'.format(item))
        else:
            for inner_l in liste:
                test(inner_l)
    else:
        print('unexpected: {}'.format(liste))
```

This technique should handle arbitrarily nested list structures. You could extend it to handle C-style nested structs.

Comment: thank you so much for you answer :) it really helped! im so close to my expected results. Do you perhaps have an idea on how i could implement a sorting algorithm that sorts the structs and their inner elements after their "position" value (last element in list) and then print it out without the values, so i get the expected results above?

Comment: also could u explain this part here: "return not isinstance(liste[0],list) and isinstance(liste[1],list) and len(liste) == 2". i understand that it returns True if liste does not contain a sublist but i dont understand why it only looks at liste[0], liste[1] and checks if len(liste) == 2

Comment: We need to tell whether a list is a struct, or just another list we need to recurse into. A C struct should always have a pattern: it is a list that contains exactly two elements, the first is a name, and the second is a list of members. Liste[0] verifies that the first item is a name not a list, liste[1] must be a list not a name, and len(liste) must be exactly two.

Comment: You already developed the basic means of sorting inner elements. You probably want to use "sorted(liste[1], key=takeFourth)". For sorting the structs by name, I'd be inclined to place each completed struct into a new list and sort that. It would be complicated to try and do it in the recursive algorithm.